# how to solve this mullti select in reactjs with typescript is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I could not able to select multiple times there is a join error code " Property 'join' does not exist on type 'unknown'." this is .tsx file

```
   const DropdownMultiselect =()=>{
        return(
            <>
            <FormControl>
                <Select
                labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
                id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
                multiple
                value={personName}
                onChange={handleChangeMulti}
                input={<Input />}
                placeholder="Enter the Scene"
                renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(',')}
                >
                    {load? <Loader/> :<div className="custom-schedule-dropdown">
                      {sceneResponce.map((scene, index) => 
                      (
                    <MenuItem key={index} value={scene.scene_title}>
                    <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(scene.set) > -1} />
                    <div className='image-background'>
                     <img src={schendileIcon.default} className="schedule-icon" />
                     </div>
                    <div>
                     <div className='schedule-scene'>{scene.scene_title+' '+ '|'}{' 
                       '+scene.environment+' '+ '-'}{' '+scene.set}</div>
                     <div className='schedule-location'>{scene.description}</div> 
                     </div>
                    </MenuItem>
                     )
                )}
                </div>}    
                </Select>
      </FormControl>
            </>
        )
    }
```

output of the screen :

[image]

when i select its is not selecting and its is not displaying too
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `unknown` actually seems like a bit of a bug in the Material UI typings.  The `Select` component should be able to infer the `value` type based on the props that you've provided.  This [has been fixed](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/499ae5763e7ee28ad868872208fac808b34d49a5) but the fix isn't going to be included until v5 is released.

You will need to set the type of `selected` as `any`.  Setting it as a more accurate type like `string[]` gives an error because of the `unknown` in the component typings.

```
renderValue={(selected: any) => selected.join(',')}
```

It looks like there are quite a lot of undefined variables in your component which should be passed as props.

Answer (score 0):

When using formik, I was able to do this (you can doctor it for your value)

```
        renderValue={(selected: typeof field['value']) => selected.join(', ')}
```